# Upgrading PostGIS 3.2.0 to 3.4.0 doesn't update

Tags: postgis

I run the following commands, but the PostGIS version continues to be 3.2.0.

```
SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();
SELECT PostGIS_Version();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command only upgrades you to the default version available in your system.
If you run the below:

```
SELECT name, default_version, installed_version
   FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name = 'postgis';
```

Look at the default_version field, that will tell you what the maximum version you can upgrade too.  If that does state 3.4.0.  Then output:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

That should give clues why you can't upgrade.